# CSV Reader does not compile special characters

Tags: csv

I am creating tables from a csv file by using "csvsimple" package. The "autotabular" option is included, so that I don't have to manually count the number of cells and manually set the cell alignment. Whenever there is a "\" in the first row of the file, it does not work; at the same time, the backslash does not cause any issue when put in the other parts of the csv file. Please help.

My code is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
$\theta$,0.4,0.7,1.0,1.3
0.201,1.001,1.801,4.601,3.401
0.200,1.000,1.800,2.600,$\theta$
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\csvreader[autotabular,
%full filter=\ifcsvstrcmp{\csvcoliv}{m}{\csvfilteraccept}{\csvfilterreject}
]{\jobname.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf) (section 5.3) states that _If needed, the data file may contain macro code. Note that the first character of a data line is not allowed to be the backslash ’\’._ This is probably a related issue.